# Explicit formula for Neumann heat kernel

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-calculus

It is well-known that
$u(x,y,t)=(4\pi t)^{-n/2}(e^{-|x-y|/4t}+e^{-|x-y'|/4t})$, $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n_+=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n|x_n\geq 0\}$, $y'=(y_1,\dots,y_{n-1},-y_n)$, is Neumann heat kernel of $\partial_tu-\Delta_yu=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n_+$, $\partial_{y_n}u=0$ on $\partial\mathbb{R}^n_+$.

Is there any other explicit example of Neumann heat kernels?

Comment: A quarter-plane  and analogues in higher dimensions.Also in one dimension on a segment  as series.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. However, I would like to see explicit examples in the higher dimension, $B(x,R)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ or hemisphere, for example. I don't know if that's possible.